# IAutoComplete with ComboBox does not trigger OnChange event

Tags: delphi, combobox, autocomplete, delphi-5

### Short Version

How do i make **OnChange** event fire when the text in the combobox changes?

### Long version

I am using [**IAutoComplete2**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/nn-shldisp-iautocomplete) to add an *"auto-suggest"* (*i.e.* drop-down) list to a Combobox.

As the user selects different options in the suggestion list, the text in the combobox changes, but unfortunately no [**OnChange**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomCombo.OnChange) event fires:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVAO4.jpg

When attaching the **AutoComplete** to a naked [**TEdit**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit) the [**OnChange**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.OnChange) event **is** fired.

```
function SHAutoCompleteComboShell(AComboBox: TComboBox): IAutoComplete2;
var
    cbi: TComboBoxInfo;
    hEdit: HWND; //A handle to the edit box.
    strings: IEnumString;
    ac: IAutoComplete2;
const
    Default_TComboBoxInfo: TComboBoxInfo = ();
begin
    //Example public domain pseudocode on how to autocomplete a combobox. 
    Result := nil;
    if AComboBox = nil then
        Exit;

    //Get the EDIT control inside the Combobox
    cbi := Default_TComboBoxInfo;
    cbi.cbSize := sizeof(TComboBoxInfo);
    if not GetComboBoxInfo(AComboBox.Handle, {var}cbi) then
        Exit;
    hEdit := cbi.hwndItem; //A handle to the edit box.
    if hEdit = 0 then
        Exit;

    //Suggest strings from the shell namespace
    strings := CreateComObject(CLSID_ACListISF) as IEnumString;

    ac:= CreateComObject(CLSID_IAutoComplete) as IAutoComplete2;
    ac.Init(hEdit, strings, nil, nil);
    ac.SetOptions(ACO_AUTOSUGGEST);

    Result := ac;
end;
```

Even as the user does the final <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select an option, the TComboBox's **OnChange** still never fires.

I assume the Windows [**Edit**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-controls#:%7E:text=An%20edit%20control%20is%20a%20rectangular%20control%20window,notifies%20the%20application%20when%20the%20operations%20are%20completed.) control is sending an [**EN_CHANGE**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change) notification message that its text has changed; but the TComboBox isn't caring.

The TComboBox is, of course, in `csDropDown` style (otherwise why would i be asking the question).

Tried in <kbd>Delphi 5</kbd> (where **[TComboBoxEx](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TComboBoxEx)** doesn't exist), <kbd>Delphi XE6</kbd>

Comment: It seems to work well in a `TComboBoxEx` (that is, a [`ComboBoxEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/comboboxex-controls) control -- get the edit handle using [CBEM_GETEDITCONTROL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cbem-geteditcontrol)). Are you willing to use such a control instead?